# Merge replication SQL Server 2008 publisher with SQL Server 2012 subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

is this somehow possible to have SQL Server 2008 publisher with a SQL Server 2012 subscriber for merge replication?

Answer (score 5):

No.  With Merge, a Subscriber can be any version no later than the Publisher version.  This is covered in [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx).